# Couchbase .NET client constructor fails to initialize properly

Tags: .net, constructor, couchbase

I've been having an issue that began with the update to 1.3.3. When I try to initialize the constructor, it hangs almost all the time. I created a simple test application to test it out, and have verified across two test clusters I setup (with 2 nodes each).

I downloaded the Couchbase .NET SDK source from github and added a test project to it to try tracking down where the issue is occuring, and it looks like it is in `Couchbase.BucketConfigListener.Start()`.

`reset.WaitOne()` never returns.

Digging deeper, I saw that the issue was in `Couchbase.MessageStreamListener.ReadMessages(Uri heartBeatUrl, Uri configUrl)`. It looks like `this.response = this.request.GetResponse();` (line 395) is what is hanging, then timing out, and throwing an exception.

I looked at the traffic with fiddler and it looks (to me) like everything is okay:

Request:

> GET http://:8091/pools/default/bucketsStreaming/syncpuppylocal?bucket_uuid= HTTP/1.1
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Authorization: Basic 
>   Host: :8091
>   Connection: Close

Response:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Server: Couchbase Server
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Date: Sun, 16 Dec 2007 21:49:24 GMT
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   Cache-Control: no-cache

The test cluster is running the latest version of Couchbase server version: 2.5.0 enterprise edition (build-1059-rel)

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you turn up the logging level on the client?  This area has pretty good logging, so it may be more clear after the logging is increased.  This doesn't sound like any known issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this finally figured out. I was running fiddler2 to inspect the contents of the web requests/responses. However, that was interfering with the bucketsStreaming URI.

Once I closed out fiddler2 and made sure no other proxies were in place, it worked just fine. I was able to also reproduce the issue on demand by restarting fiddler2 before trying to initialize the constructor.

Hope this helps others that have this issue!

Comment: Feel free to mark your response as "answered" so the Q isn't left open.